# HQL: order all items by a specific item in its map

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, hql

I am quite new to Hibernate and currently struggling a bit with HQL. I have the following mapping and would like to get all "Industry" entities ordered by the "translation" for a given "culture_id"

Code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Domain.Industry, Core" table="industry">

    <id name="ID" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>

    <map name="AllNames"
      access="nosetter.camelcase-underscore"
      table="_dict_industry_name"
      cascade="all-delete-orphan">
      <key column="record_id"></key>
      <index column="culture_id" type="Int32"></index>
      <element column="translation" type="String"></element>
    </map>

  </class>
  </hibernate-mapping>
```

I tried the following:
Code:

```
from Industry industry order by elements(industry.AllNames[:lcid])
```

but it does not work...

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there was no answer posted I have asked it in some other forums. Here are two possible solutions:

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=996853

http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/1750d64ecdeb72f9

I prefer this one:

```
from Industry industry
where index(industry) = :lcid
order by industry.AllNames
```